# Get count of a list effectively with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema like this.

```
peopleSchema = Schema({
    followerRefs: {
        type: [
            { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'peoples'}
        ],
        select: false
    },
    followRefs: {
        type: [
            { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'peoples'}
        ],
        select: false
    },
})
```

Because the `followerRefs` and the `followRefs` may have many objects, I set the select option to false. However, every time I fetch the people entity, I want to know the count of `follwerRefs` and `followRef`. So I am wondering whether there are any way to get the count of the two list effectively (without select them) in mongoose or native mongoDB?